# DRF non-writable nested serializer related field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django 3.2 and DRF

I have a serializer with nested serializer fields like

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = [
            'id',
            'title',
        ]


class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    category = CategorySerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = [
            'category',
            'title',
            'description'
        ]
```

Where in response the data should be returned like

```
{
  "category": {
    "id": 4,
    "title": "General Knowledge",
    "created": "2021-05-23T07:12:14.749571Z",
    "modified": "2021-05-23T07:12:14.749639Z"
  },
  "title": "Where is Delhi?",
  "description": ""
}
```

This is fine, but with the **POST** method, I don't want to create nested data for the `Category` because these records are only created from the admin panel.

But these fields are required to create the `Question` record.

When passing the `id` of the category in the payload, it still says the `category` field is required.

[image]

How can I assign a related field using the `id` of the object instead of passing all data to create a nested object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = [
            'category',
            'title',
            'description',
        ]

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        data = super().to_representation(instance)
        data['category'] = CategorySerializer(
            Category.objects.get(pk=data['category'])).data
        return data
```

Try it.

Comment: I don't want to have two fields for the same purpose.

Comment: I used `instance.category` instead of running an extra query. The category is prefetched with the instance.

Comment: I missed that. Nice catch dude

Answer (score 1):

Please try to add a separate serializer to create a question:

```
class QuestionListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = [
            'category',
            'title',
            'description'
        ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also set the field as not required:

```py
class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    category = CategorySerializer(required=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to create Question with existing category, client must know `category_id`.

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = [
            'id',
            'title',
        ]


class QuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    category = CategorySerializer(read_only=True)
    category_id = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        queryset=Category.objects.all(), source="category", write_only=True
    )  # You can add required=True, if you want to require this field on creation

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = [
            'category',
            'category_id',
            'title',
            'description'
        ]
```

In this scenario, `category` will only be visible on GET requests (e.g. `QuestionSerializer(instance).data`).

And `category_id` could be passed to POST request.

`request.data`:

```json
{
    "category_id": 4,
    "title": "title1",
    "description": "description1"

}
```

```py
serializer = QuestionSerializer(data=request.data)
serializer.is_valid()
serializer.save()
serializer.data
```

After creation response(`serializer.data`) would be:

```json
{
    "category": {
        "id": 4,
        "title": "General Knowledge",
        "created": "2021-05-23T07:12:14.749571Z",
        "modified": "2021-05-23T07:12:14.749639Z"
    },
    "title": "title1",
    "description": "description1"
}
```